# How to pass value in controller action in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am redirecting a user to a custom controller action like this:

```
<%= link_to url_for(:controller => :jobs, :action => :saved) do %>Saved Jobs<% end %>
```

it works fine, now i want to pass some value to action "saved".
Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: This isn't how Rails works. If you want to pass a parameter through a link, you put it in the query string.

Answer (score 3):

**Try This**

If you want to send the form directly by reloading the page as you are doing,

```
<%= link_to url_for(:controller => :jobs, :action => :saved, method: :post, :email => "value") do %>Saved Jobs<% end %>
```

If you want to send it through ajax call from background, add `:remote => true` to the form,

```
<%= link_to url_for(:controller => :jobs, :action => :saved, method: :post, :email => "value", :remote => true) do %>Saved Jobs<% end %>
```

**Then in controller**

```
@email = params[:email]
```

Comment: simply add remote: true so you can handle it remotely without showing parameters in browser url